# What is the best way to parse text and code in my PHP blog?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, bbcode

Usually, I use `nl2br()` and it does come out just like it's entered in the textarea, but this causes a problem when using bbcode or posting code in `<code>` or `<pre>` tags, since it adds extra line breaks.

For example this code

```
[sub-title]test[/sub-title]

some text here.
```

I'd like it to look like that when displayed in the browser, but because `[sub-title]` becomes `<div class="sub-title">` the `<br />` adds an extra line break, so it will look like this (with 2 line breaks in between)

```
**test**


some text here.
```

I haven't fully looked into it yet, but could the PHP bbcode parser help, or is the only/best solution to use regex?

Comment: make the div display: inline; then you can keep doing it the way you are already doing it.

Comment: use the bbcode parser...if you do it in Regex you are making a full language definition which is beyond normal scope.

Comment: thanks guys. the only problem is if I do display: inline; I can't control the bottom margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nl2br()`

Example

```
$message =  nl2br(preg_replace('#(\\]{1})(\\s?)\\n#Usi', ']', stripslashes($message)));
```

Comment: thanks this works great. could you explain what it does though? I have an idea but not sure about the #s